# Inner while loop iteration with outer loop

Tags: c++, while-loop

I have a simple nested while loop situation but I'm not sure how to increment numGuesses inside the second loop to escape the first loop once it is no longer less than 5.

```
while(numGuesses<5){
    while(!correct){
        cout << "\nGuess the number the computer randomply picked between 1 - 100: ";
        numGuesses++;
        cin >> guess;
        if(guess<number){
            cin.clear(); //clears input stream
            cin.ignore(256, '\n');
            cout << "\nSorry, your guess is too low";
        }
        else if (guess>number){
            cout << "\nSorry, your guess is too high";
        }
        else{
            cout << "\nYou guessed right, you win!";
            correct = !correct;
        }
    }
    
}
cout << "Sorry, you lost. The number is: " << number;
```

Each time the inner while loop iterates I would like numGuesses to increase but I'm guessing its not in its scope?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should just use one while loop! After all, the thing you're looping over is prompting for a guess. There's no need for a second layer of looping inside that. Think about when you want to stop asking for a guess -- when the guesses get to 5 or when they get it correct. So when do you want to keep asking for a guess? When the guesses are less than 5 and they have not got it correct. Also, you want to say whether they lost after the end of the loop depending on the value of `correct`.

```
while(numGuesses<5 && !correct) {
    cout << "\nGuess the number the computer randomply picked between 1 - 100: ";
    numGuesses++;
    cin >> guess;
    if(guess<number){
        cin.clear(); //clears input stream
        cin.ignore(256, '\n');
        cout << "\nSorry, your guess is too low";
    }
    else if (guess>number){
        cout << "\nSorry, your guess is too high";
    }
    else{
        cout << "\nYou guessed right, you win!";
        correct = !correct;
    }
}
if (!correct) { // loop stopped before they got it correct
    cout << "Sorry, you lost. The number is: " << number;
}
```

You'll also want `"\n"`s or `std::endl`s at the end of your print statements, otherwise your code will print everything on one line.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need 2 whiles...

```
while(numGuesses < 5 && !correct)
{
       // your logic here
}
```

After that you can check either the variable **correct** or **numGuesses**. For example:

```
if(!correct)
    // your code
```